# How to stringify a string which contains a comma?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, stringification, variadic-macros

I want to pass a version string in the compile command:

```sh
$ g++ -Wall -D VERSION="2013-12-03 02:15:21, commit cb060df" -o main main.cpp
```

Inside my code, I have the following:

```
#define TOSTR_(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) TOSTR_(x)
#define VERSION_STR STRINGIFY(VERSION)
```

This doesn't work, because the `VERSION` macro has a comma in it, so it looks like I'm passing two arguments to `TOSTR()` (apparently, the `VERSION` macro only gets expanded after it's passed to `STRINGIFY()` as one unique argument).

The following approach I found in [here](http://ingomueller.net/node/1203) also doesn't work:

```
#define CONCAT(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define TOSTR_(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) TOSTR_(CONCAT(x))
#define VERSION_STR STRINGIFY(VERSION)
```

bacause this appears to be the same as

```
#define VERSIONSTR "CONCAT(2013-12-03 02:15:21, commit cb060df)"
```

that is, the macro `CONCAT()` doesn't get expanded.

Note 1: I would rather not pass a **C** string in the command line, because the version string is actually dynamically generated, and it might contain some quotes. This means that just writing `g++ -D VERSION=\""$(GENERATED_STRING)"\"` instead of stringifying the passed argument wouldn't work.

Note 2: I would be extremely happy if someone found a way of doing this without any preprocessor macros at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write the `TOSTR_` macro to take variable arguments:

```
#define TOSTR_(x...) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) TOSTR_(x)
#define VERSION_STR STRINGIFY(VERSION)
```

This code has been tested and works on Apple LLVM version 5.0.

Comment: For the record: I'm getting the warning "ISO C++ does not permit **named** variadic macros" (emphasis mine). To get rid of it, just chage `#define TOSTR_(x...) #x` to `#define TOSTR_(...) #__VA_ARGS__`.

Answer (score 4):

__VA_ARGS__ must be in each call:

```
#define _STRINGIZE(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define STRINGIZE(...) _STRINGIZE(__VA_ARGS__)
```